# Word order and expressing time

Tags: usage, particles

How do you say: I have been learning Japanese for several months'.

I've come up with '日本語は数ヶ月を習っています。'Or would the word order '数ヶ月に日本語を習っています。' be more precise.

Also, how do I say 'the coming [month]'? Eg 'This coming April I have some time off work.'

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

> > How do you say: I have been learning Japanese for several months'.
> >
> > I've come up with '日本語は数ヶ月を習っています。'Or would the word order '数ヶ月に日本語を習っています。' be more precise.

The answer is （私は（implied))日本語を数ヶ月習っています。

Now, first of all, please be reminded 数ヶ月 ( for several months ) is an adverb.

Here is an English site.

http://www.japaneselanguageguide.com/grammar/adverb.asp

Down below near the bottom, there is "Adverbs that don't derive from adjectives" list.

And you can see there, 毎朝,毎日,明日etc etc denoting the time. So likewise these,
数ヶ月 is an adverb and what is modifying is "習っています”． ( = be learning ).

So for the last one, を, the particle. What do you learn? Yes, it is 日本語。

Thus,　the answer is 日本語を（object)数か月習っています(verb)。

It conforms with Japanese SOV style. ( Like English, adverbs modify verbs, auxiliary, adjective, right? So, between 日本語を and 習っています, comes the adverb 数ヵ月。

> > Also, how do I say 'the coming [month]'? Eg 'This coming April I have some time off　work.'

The answer is この4月に暫(しばら）く休暇（きゅうか）を取ります。

Now, 休暇（きゅうか）を取ります。 is like as the first one, "take the time off"
So, the grammar is OV. 暫（しばら）く, an adverb, denoting "some time"

このis, in English "This", thus "coming" is inferred.

Here is an English site for Japanese demonstrative adjective

http://www.japaneselanguageguide.com/grammar/demonstrative-adjective.asp

So, 4月, April, に is a particle, denoting, when ( in this case ), thus the answer will be
like "In this April, I am going to take some time off work".

Good luck.

Comment: Hum, you say that the adverb, like 毎日, should come just before the verb. Yet, in the page you link, the example given is : "私は毎朝学校に行く". I think you should maybe put more emphasis on how to choose the order of the words (See here : http://nihongoperapera.com/dirty-japanese-guide-word-order.html where they actually recommend to put the time marker before the object!). On top of this, shouldn't this particular sentence use 数ヶ月間 to express a duration ?

Comment: If you understand so much, kindly answer to the questioner instead. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don't take this as a critic. I do not master Japanese at all, but when I read your post, I really thought that word order is a broader topic than just "SOV". And no, I will not answer, I don't think I can be as thorough as you were, I am suggesting improvements to the answer :)

Comment: Hmmm... I understand. However, kindly be reminded when I look at the questioner's question, I thought it is more about basic grammar rather than word order. ( If you say word order is grammar too, yes. ) I may think and try as much as possible so that beginners feel easier to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Lastly, not for trying to justify myself, but cramming word order to such a fresh start learner ( for a few weeks ) is too much, I think. So I'd like to end here as for now and personally hope that the questioners can distinguish and learn what particle he/she needs to use after the object and verb conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

This is two questions?

**First:**

> 'I have been learning Japanese for several months.'

```
私は数ヶ月間日本語を習っています。
```

Correction:
the meaning of "間"(or"の間") is same as 'for'

```
日本語は数ヶ月を習っています。 NG  
日本語を数ヶ月間習っています。 OK  

数ヶ月に日本語を習っています。 NG
数ヶ月間日本語を習っています。 OK
```

**Second:**

> 'the coming [month]'  e.g.'This coming April'

```
次のXX月 e.g.今年の四月
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes it's two questions, ^^U